# sending variables via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have sent values of form fields are sent using val().. i want to send plain php variables to via ajax, this is id values

```
   var dminute= $("#dminute").val();

var dataString = 'dminute='+ dminute + '&dhour=' + dhour + '&minuteid1=' + minuteid1+ '&hourid1=' + hourid1+ '&datepicker=' + datepicker;
```

for php variable, how should i send?

```
   var dminute=$dminute;
```

is a wrong syntax.. If someone would, tell how to send this..Thanks in advances..

Answer (score 1):

you can use php tags.. if your codes in not in seperate .js file

try this

```
var dminute= <?php echo $dminute ?>;
```

Comment: ya, will use php tags.. Thanks u

Comment: the variable is send as empty.. it has value, but sends that way.. @bipen

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign your php variable to javascript var,

```
var dminute= <?php echo $dminute;?>;
```

Comment: it is working but the values is not passing, does this have some scope ??

Comment: variable has a value.. i checked.. but it sends empty... any idea??

Comment: Show more code. Is that value being assigned to your JS variable before you make the request? There is nothing to confuse with scope

Comment: Cool buddy :) If you are able to see the value in an alert or console before you make the AJAX request, and still value is not passed, please post it as a separate question with more code. Don't confuse multiple issues

Comment: it is accepting session variable, but doesn't take normal.. anyway will sort it out.. Thanks for ur time and interest :) @bipen